Holdout and Alpha White Edges
I was wondering how I'd go about getting rid of the edges not matching in this scene. I'm using two scenes.



The outer shell that has a hole with a holdout material inset for one of the faces
The inside where basically everything else has the holdout material except the tunnel inside.

Whenever I composite the two alpha layers together, I notice a bit of a light edge where the layers meet.
What can I do about this?
Render, Holdout Material & Compositor Settings




Do you need the frame to show a hole in the shadow? If not, why do use a holdout material for the center of the frame? You can alpha over the sphere window without that. Also, holdout is not alpha transparency. No need to set the Blend Mode to Alpha Clip, you can leave it at Opaque, same goes for the Shadow Mode. By the way, when I render your file (withot making my suggested changes) I do not see a light edge. Rather a dark edge, but not very distracting.

Thank you! I'll keep these recommendations in mind for future reference.

The ridge comes from a little transparency left on edges, so if you compose this image over  a white background some white will show through.
To solve, uncheck "Use Alpha" option on viewer and composite nodes, or add another Alpha over node to precompose the image over a dark red background.


Thanks! This works too. I actually ended up figuring it out by adding a alpha convert node and changing the mode to "to straight". I appreciate your help!
